# For loop comparing values of 2 dataframes putting output results of the test in 3rd dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, compare, output

I want to compare 2 dataframes in R if their values are exactly the same. Sort of a test. If the value of df1(row1, column1) == extactly the same of the value of df2(row1, column1) it should return "OK" in that same position in an empty 3rd dataframe(row1, column1) which I want to fill with the output testresults of the comparing. If not it should return "PROBLEM" in that position. The secon iteration would than be position 2, position 3 and so on until the test is thru al the values of df1 and df 2. --> df1 and df2 have the same number of columns and the same number of rows (150 rows and 6 columns), df3 is empty and must be filled with the output results.

I am quite new to for loops and suffer a lot from trial and error. So far I tried this: As testdata I used the Iris dataset. Dataframes Iris1 and Iris2 should be the same. To test if my for loop works I manually changed 2 random values in Iris2. Iris3 is the empty dataframe which I want to fill with the output testresults. As you can see I am now trying with the simple print function, but that doesn't work as well and is not what I want to do here. I want the output to be stored in df3. Hopefully someone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

```
Iris3 <- Iris1[FALSE,]

  for (i in 1:(length(Iris1))) {
for(j in 1:(length(Iris2))) {
    if(Iris1[[i]] == Iris2[[i]]) {
      print("OK")
    }
    else print("PROBLEM")
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a loop. You can simply compare `Iris1 == Iris2` and use the result to get values from a vector.

```
Iris1 <- Iris2 <- Iris3 <- iris

Iris2[1,1] <- 0
Iris2[2,2] <- 0

Iris3[] <- c("PROBLEM", "OK")[1+(Iris1 == Iris2)]

head(Iris3)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1      PROBLEM          OK           OK          OK      OK
#2           OK     PROBLEM           OK          OK      OK
#3           OK          OK           OK          OK      OK
#4           OK          OK           OK          OK      OK
#5           OK          OK           OK          OK      OK
#6           OK          OK           OK          OK      OK
```

In case you want to make use of a for loop:

```
for(i in seq_along(Iris1)) {
  Iris3[i] <- ifelse(Iris1[i] == Iris2[i], "OK", "PROBLEM")
}
```

Comment: Thanks GKi. Your solution works, but 2 things: 1; I don't understand why you do the "1+"? 2;The point is also that I want to learn how to do this with a for loop.

Comment: Because `Iris1 == Iris2` returns boolean (TRUE or FALSE) which will be converted to 1 and 0 and the index of a vector starts in R with 1. So I add 1.

Comment: I have add a way using a for loop.

Comment: Thanks again GKi. Okay I understand that now, that helps. I can follow the forloop, but now got a new problem, keep getting this error: "Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c("OK", "OK", "OK", "OK",  : 
  replacement has 150 rows, data has 0"

Comment: Thanks a lot GKi! It works now. Problem was that I signed the empty dataframe (Iris3) like this: "Iris3 <- Iris1[FALSE, ]" causing it only to have the columns of Iris1 but not the rows (because I wanted to be an empty dataframe with no values). Problem solved when I signed it like this: "Iris3 <- Iris1". The for loop overrides all the values to "OK" or "PROBLEM" so it hadn't have to be empty. In my thoughts I kept holding to the need of an empty dataframe to fill it with the for loop iterations.